# How do I safely join relative url segments?

Tags: ruby, uri

I'm trying to find a robust method of joining partial url path segments together. Is there a quick way to do this?

I tried the following:

```
puts URI::join('resource/', '/edit', '12?option=test')
```

I expect:

```
resource/edit/12?option=test
```

But I get the error:

```
`merge': both URI are relative (URI::BadURIError)
```

I have used `File.join()` in the past for this but something does not seem right about using the file library for urls.

Comment: "something does not seem right about using the file library for urls", that is correct. `File.join` is sensitive to the OS and will change the character used as the separator, depending on the OS. That would give you bad results.

Answer (score 26):

URI's API is not necessarily great.

`URI::join` will work only if the first one starts out as an absolute URI with protocol, and the later ones are relative in the right ways... except I try to do that and can't even get that to work.

This at least doesn't error, but why is it skipping the middle component?

```
 URI::join('http://somewhere.com/resource', './edit', '12?option=test')
```

I think maybe URI just kind of sucks. It lacks significant API on instances, such as an instance `#join` or method to evaluate relative to a base uriURI that you'd expect. It's just kinda crappy.

I think you're going to have to write it yourself. Or just use `File.join` and other File path methods, after testing all the edge cases you can think of to make sure it does what you want/expect.

**edit** 9 Dec 2016 I figured out the [addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem does it very nicely.

```
base = Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com")
base + "foo.html"
# => #<Addressable::URI:0x3ff9964aabe4 URI:http://example.com/foo.html>
 
base = Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com/path/to/file.html")
base + "relative_file.xml"
# => #<Addressable::URI:0x3ff99648bc80 URI:http://example.com/path/to/relative_file.xml>
 
base = Addressable::URI.parse("https://example.com/path")
base + "//newhost/somewhere.jpg"
# => #<Addressable::URI:0x3ff9960c9ebc URI:https://newhost/somewhere.jpg>
 
base = Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com/path/subpath/file.html")
base + "../up-one-level.html"
=> #<Addressable::URI:0x3fe13ec5e928 URI:http://example.com/path/up-one-level.html>
```

Comment: Do not forget to do `to_s` if you need `String` version of uri, otherwise you get `URI::HTTP` object

Comment: `Addresable` skips the middle segment as well if there is more than one. e.g. `(Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com") + "abc" + "xyz").to_s` generates `http://example.com/xyz`. Years after my original answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067748/345034) on this question, I still think `File.join` is the safest way to join URL segments. :D

Answer (score 10):

Have uri as `URI::Generic` or subclass of thereof

```
uri.path += '/123'
```

Enjoy!

**06/25/2016 UPDATE** for skeptical folk

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI('http://ioffe.net/boris')
uri.path += '/123'
p uri
```

Outputs

```
 <URI::HTTP:0x2341a58 URL:http://ioffe.net/boris/123>
```

[Run me](https://repl.it/E0Ar/0)

Comment: This replaces the entire path component with '/123', it doesn't extend the existing path.

Comment: Here's what I get:

uri = URI("httpx://example.com/mypath/"); uri+= '/123'

=> #<URI::HTTPS https://example.com/123>

Comment: @AneilMallavarapu you should consider that you doing something wrong. In this case you should use url.path instead of url. Please look carefully at  the sample I provided, before down-voting a legit answer.

Answer (score 9):

The way to do it using URI.join is:

`URI.join('http://example.com', '/foo/', 'bar')`

Pay attention to the trailing slashes. You can find the complete documentation here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-join

Comment: If you need to manage the leading and trailing slashes yourself, what's the point of using this method in the first place?

Comment: You get a URI::HTTP object in this case. Though you have a valid point, and I generally use `File.join('http://example.com', '/foo/', 'bar')` when I need a string and it takes care of slashes.

PS: I work solely on linux based systems and servers, so I don't face the file separator issue described above.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `resource/` is relative to the current directory, but `/edit` refers to the top level directory due to the leading slash.  It's impossible to join the two directories without already knowing for certain that `edit` contains `resource`.

If you're looking for purely string operations, simply remove the leading or trailing slashes from all parts, then join them with `/` as the glue.

Comment: Well, unless you're not working at the domain root, in which case the leading `/` on the first part would make a difference.

Comment: That's easy to force using an empty string as a first parameter.

Answer (score 7):

As you noticed, `URI::join` won't combine paths with repeated slashes, so it doesn't fit the part.

Turns out it doesn't require a lot of Ruby code to achieve this:

```
module GluePath

  def self.join(*paths, separator: '/')
    paths = paths.compact.reject(&:empty?)
    last = paths.length - 1
    paths.each_with_index.map { |path, index|
      _expand(path, index, last, separator)
    }.join
  end

  def self._expand(path, current, last, separator)
    if path.start_with?(separator) && current != 0
      path = path[1..-1]
    end

    unless path.end_with?(separator) || current == last
      path = [path, separator]
    end

    path
  end
end
```

The algorithm takes care of consecutive slashes, preserves start and end slashes, and ignores `nil` and empty strings.

```
puts GluePath::join('resource/', '/edit', '12?option=test')
```

outputs

```
resource/edit/12?option=test
```

Comment: Actually, `File.join` does not use a backslash separator on Windows. It uses a forward slash (`/`), just as on Linux.

Comment: In case it helps others, the `starts_with?` and the `ends_with?` probably needs to be `start_with?` and `end_with?` respectively.

Comment: Edited the answer to be compatible with the Ruby standard library, without the Active Support extensions.

Answer (score 2):

This question is nearly a decade old, yet it seems that there is no perfect solution posted.

A handful of posted answers fail to handle multiple `//`, e.g. stuff like `path = path[1..-1] if path.start_with?('/')`

Answers that simply call `File.join(*paths)` seem to be the accepted "Ruby way," yet they fail in cases where you pass a `URI` object, e.g. `File.join(URI.join('some/path'))` fails with `TypeError: no implicit conversion of URI::Generic into String`.

Below is what I ended up using:

```
module UrlHelper
  def self.join(*paths)
    # yes, Ruby's stdlib really does lack a functional join method for URLs
    File.join(*paths.map(&:to_s))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
File.join('resource/', '/edit', '12?option=test').
     gsub(File::SEPARATOR, '/').
     sub(/^\//, '')
# => resource/edit/12?option=test
```

example with empty strings:

```
File.join('', '/edit', '12?option=test').
     gsub(File::SEPARATOR, '/').
     sub(/^\//, '')
# => edit/12?option=test
```

Or use this if possible to use segments like `resource/`, `edit/`, `12?option=test` and where `http:` is only a placeholder to get a valid URI. This works for me.

```
URI.
  join('http:', 'resource/', 'edit/', '12?option=test').
  path.
  sub(/^\//, '')
# => "resource/edit/12"
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work on Windows machine, where the separator is a backslash.

Comment: Thats true. You need to set the separator.

Answer (score 1):

A not optimized solution. Note that it doesn't take query params into account. It only handles paths.

```
class URL
  def self.join(*str)
    str.map { |path|
      new_path = path
      # Check the first character
      if path[0] == "/"
        new_path = new_path[1..-1]
      end

      # Check the last character
      if path[-1] != "/"
        new_path += "/"
      end

      new_path
    }.join
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my simple take on this problem, just splitting up all the path segments and join them together again. This only works if you're only working with relative path segments, but if that's all you want to do this is handy.

```rb
def join_paths *paths
  paths.map{|p| p.split('/')}
       .flatten
       .reject(&:empty?)
       .compact
       .join('/')
end
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
join_paths 'foo/', '/bar', 'a/b/c', 'd' #=> "foo/bar/a/b/c/d"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.join('resource/', '/edit', '12?option=test')`

Comment: This is a lucky coincidence, but it is not the right method to call to express your intention.

Comment: Will this not use \ on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I improved @Maximo Mussini's script to make it works gracefully:

```
SmartURI.join('http://example.com/subpath', 'hello', query: { token: secret })
=> "http://example.com/subpath/hello?token=secret"
```

https://gist.github.com/zernel/0f10c71f5a9e044653c1a65c6c5ad697

```
require 'uri'

module SmartURI
  SEPARATOR = '/'

  def self.join(*paths, query: nil)
    paths = paths.compact.reject(&:empty?)
    last = paths.length - 1
    url = paths.each_with_index.map { |path, index|
      _expand(path, index, last)
    }.join
    if query.nil?
      return url
    elsif query.is_a? Hash
      return url + "?#{URI.encode_www_form(query.to_a)}"
    else
      raise "Unexpected input type for query: #{query}, it should be a hash."
    end
  end

  def self._expand(path, current, last)
    if path.starts_with?(SEPARATOR) && current != 0
      path = path[1..-1]
    end

    unless path.ends_with?(SEPARATOR) || current == last
      path = [path, SEPARATOR]
    end

    path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
URI.join('http://exemple.com', '/a/', 'b/', 'c/', 'd')
=> #<URI::HTTP http://exemple.com/a/b/c/d>
URI.join('http://exemple.com', '/a/', 'b/', 'c/', 'd').to_s
=> "http://exemple.com/a/b/c/d"
```

See: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-join-label-Synopsis

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of `URI::join` is that it thinks like a web browser does.

To evaluate it, point your mental web browser to the first parameter, and keep clicking links until you browse to the last parameter.

For example, `URI::join('http://example.com/resource/', '/edit', '12?option=test')`, you would browse like this:

- http://example.com/resource/, click a link to `/edit` (a file at the root of the site)
- http://example.com/edit, click a link to `12?option=test` (a file in the same directory as `edit`)
- http://example.com/12?option=test

If the first link were `/edit/` (with a trailing slash), or `/edit/foo`, then the next link would be relative to `/edit/` rather than `/`.

This page possibly explains it better than I can: [Why is URI.join so counterintuitive?](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/why-is-uri-join-so-counterintuitive/)