# Join two relative urls

Tags: ruby

I have the following case that I want to join two relative urls:
`/api/v1/` and `/status`.

I already searched how I can accomplish this but the only two solutions I found were to use `URI::join` or `File.join`.
`URI::join` only works if the first url segment is absolute which is not the case. Using `File.join` works but doesn't feel right in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I safely join relative url segments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900782/how-do-i-safely-join-relative-url-segments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Addressable gem](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) solves the problem:

```
require "addressable/uri"

fragment1 = '/api/v1/'

fragment2 = 'status'

Addressable::URI.join(fragment1, fragment2).to_s
# => "/api/v1/status"
```